# How would I implement word count and not allow certain words in one regex in google forms

Tags: regex, google-forms

In google forms you can only have 1 form of response validation. I would like to have two: word count and not allowing certain words.

I was able to select "doesn't contain" with the pattern \b(apple|orange|banana|fruit)\b .

I was able to figure out that if I select "doesn't contain" with the pattern ^[-\w]+(?:\W+[-\w]+){249,999999}\W*$ to limit word count.

However I want to be able to do both and I am not sure how to do this.

The question is for a grant application so the question would be What creative solution are you solving.
The response would be a paragraph or two and they can not include their school name or mascot.

Comment: The question is for a grant application so the question would be What creative solution are you solving. The response would be a paragraph or two and they can not include their school name or mascot.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that it would be a pretty complicated expression, not so sure though; maybe, we would start with an expression similar to:

```
^(?!.*(?:\bHarvard-Westlake\b|\bPhillips\b\s\bExeter\b|\bTrinity\s+\bSchool\b).*).*$
```

on `s` mode, and most likely we'd want to list the names of all probable schools, if known, to a list using alternation.

---

Also not sure if lookarounds are supported in Google Forms.

---

#### Char Count

The expression can be modified to,

```
^(?!.*(?:\bHarvard-Westlake\b|\bPhillips\b\s\bExeter\b|\bTrinity\s+\bSchool\b).*).{249,9999}$
```

if char count would be also necessary.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y9Dr95/1/)

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
> explained on the top right panel of
> [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ljeWqs/1/). If you'd like, you
> can also watch in [this
> link](https://regex101.com/r/ljeWqs/1/debugger), how it would match
> against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: What is S mode?

Comment: it is not working, I know that my expressions both work the way they need to. I just need to figure out how to combine them.